# Google Map marker and current location not showing

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

Google Map marker and current location not showing
i am a beginner and  making laundry app i added google map in fragment map is showing fine but map marker is not displaying even adding marker manually but marker not showing and current location also unable to show

```
 @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                mMap.clear();
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Your Current Location").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }
        };

        askLocationPermission();

    }

    private void askLocationPermission() {
        Dexter.withActivity(this).withPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION).withListener(new PermissionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    return;
                }
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
                Location lastlocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                latLng = new LatLng(lastlocation.getLatitude(), lastlocation.getLongitude());
                mMap.clear();
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Your Current Location").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

            }

            @Override
            public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {
                token.continuePermissionRequest();

            }
        }).check();

    }

 i am a beginner and  making laundry app i added google map in fragment map is showing fine but map marker is not displaying even adding marker manually but marker not showing and current location also unable to show
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMWsY.png)

Comment: Did you accept location permission?

Comment: i added location permission to manifest file but when run the app it does not required any permission.

Comment: Do you add location permission in manifest?

Comment: yes already added

Comment: Is it access fine location permission? Or coarse loaction permission?

Comment: Are you using a valid API key from a project with billing enabled, Maps SDK for Android enabled and Places API enabled? Also please can you share the errors you get if any?

Comment: yes i check all these thing problem is not error is displaying in logcat

Comment: I see, can you please post your full code so that we can reproduce this issue from our side?